# Проблема с IIS 404 - Файл или каталог не найден

Tags: html5, iis

Приветствую! В IIS есть *default web site*, который смотрит на папку "*c:\wwwroot\inetpub*". Для него добавлен виртуальный каталог (путь *d:/MyFolder/*), в котором лежит *index.html* с таким кодом:

```
<html>
  <body>
    Hello!
    <br>
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src="vidosik.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
  </body>
</html>
```

Если открывать html файл в браузере. то файл проигрывается. Но если открыть через `url` *localhost/mysite*, то в *network* пишет:

> 404 - Файл или каталог не найден

Файл видео лежит в той же папке, что и *index.html*. Пробовал ложить файл в папку "*c:\wwwroot\inetpub*", не помогло. Почему не находит файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перейдите в раздел MIME Types, добавьте `extension: .mp4 MIME type: video/mp4`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо, за ответ, вечером проверю